# What is the simplest way to store and retrieve my error values with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, refactoring

In my gem I have errors messages that I keep repeating like this:

```
def validate_configuration!
   fail(ArgumentError, "You must specify a valid access_key") if access_key.nil? || access_key.empty?
   fail(ArgumentError, "You must specify a valid access_token") if access_token.nil? || access_token.empty? 
   fail(ArgumentError, "You must specify a valid environment") if environment.nil? || environment.empty?
end
```

and then in my tests I repeat the same:

```
it "is required and cannot be a blank string" do
   expect { create_client(access_key: nil) }.to  raise_error(ArgumentError, "You must specify a valid access_key")
   expect { create_client(access_key: '') }.to raise_error(ArgumentError, "You must specify a valid access_key")
end
```

I would like to store all of these messages in a separate file in some kind of object(this is the confusing part) and then access them like so:

```
messages.nil_error_for(:access_key)
messages.empty_error_for(:access_key)
```

Even better I would like to skip the messages variable altogether if possible.

Should I use a Struct, a Module? What idiomatic data structure in ruby is ideal for this scenario?

Comment: Do you really have to check for `nil`? What would happen if you would just remove the check?

Comment: If I removed the `nil` check, I would not get the explicit error message I want to show the user no?

Comment: The user would not get _that_ error message, but another error will eventually be raised, because `nil` does not respond to the methods you are sending it.

Comment: that's true - user would get a default message. So what is your advice here @Stefan? Does the custom message add no value?

Comment: Unless something really bad or strange is going to happen if that value is `nil` or empty string, I would not raise a custom exception. The user is most likely a developer and has a good reason to pass that value. Maybe he's writing a unit test and doesn't really care about `access_key` ;-)